# Prove that the set of integers bounded below is well-ordered.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given that we have some $r \in \mathbb{R}$, demonstrate that the set $ S=\{n\in \mathbb{Z} : r\leq n\}$ is well-ordered.

I first tried to demonstrate that there exists exactly one integer on the half-open interval $(r,r+1]$ (because I had used that as a Lemma for a previous assignment) and then proceed inductively to show that any subset would admit a least element.  However, that proof required that I assume that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered.  The point of this assignment is to use this result as a Lemma to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered, so I cannot use that assumption.

It seems obvious to me that the only thing keeping $\mathbb{Z}$ from being well-ordered is that it is unbounded on the negative side. However, seeing that this lower bound eliminates that problem and demonstrating that an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ must admit a least element has proven more difficult for me than I expected.  The level for the question is an undergraduate intro to Set Theory.

It turns out the intention of the professor was to have us prove that every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is well ordered if and only if every descending sequence of that subset stabilizes.  Off to work on that one now.

Comment: Do you have any examples of infinite sets you already know to be well-ordered? Or: How is $\mathbb Z$ constructed if not starting from $\mathbb N$, which is wellordered per Peano axioms or as an ordinal ... Maybe you start with a complete ordered field $\mathbb R$ and let $\mathbb Z$ be the smallest additive subgroup containing $1$?

Comment: We have only addressed $\mathbb{N}$ in this course so far.

Comment: Do you know that finite subsets of $\mathbb R$ are wellordered? And that $(a,b)\cap \mathbb Z$ is always at most finite?

Comment: That's not something that I've used, though if I can formulate a Lemma then I can use it.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you can use and what not. I repeat: What is your definition of $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Our text gives what I expect is not what you were looking for: $\mathbb{Z} = \{..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3,... \}$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8528/discussion-between-hagen-von-eitzen-and-s3anz13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following proof assumes the following is known:

- For $a,b\in\mathbb R$, the set $[a,b]\cap \mathbb Z$ is finite.
- A total order on a finite set is a well-order.

We have to show that every nonempty subset $A$ of $S$ has a minimal element.
As $A\ne \emptyset$, let $a\in A$ be some element of $A$.
Then $B:=\{x\in A\mid x\le a\}$ is nonempty and finite because it is in fact $\mathbb Z\cap [r,a]$.
Hence $B$ is well-ordered. Let $b=\min B$. Then $b=\min A$ because for $x\in A$ we have either $x\le a$ and then $b\le x$ because $x\in B$; or we have $x>a$ and then $x\le a<x$ directly.